# Why does casting a primitive type to a reference type is giving compilation error?

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types, reference-type

I am wondering why casting a primitive data type (`int` for instance) to a reference type (`Long` for instance) does not compile?

```
BinaryOperator<Long> add = (x, y) -> x + y;
System.out.println(add.apply((Long)8, (Long)5)); //this line does not compile
System.out.println(add.apply((long)8, (long)5)); // this line does compile
```

I will be happy to have some detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: Does `(Long)8l` compile? And here's a further [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7](hint).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this

```
Long l = 1;
```

means assigning an `int` (literal number without floating part are `int`) to an `Object`, here a `Long`.
The autoboxing feature introduced in Java 5 doesn't allow to box from an `int` to something else than a `Integer`. So `Long` is not acceptable as target type but this one would be :

```
Integer i = 1;
```

In your working example you convert the int to a long : `(long)8`.
So the compiler can perfectly box `long` to `Long`.

Comment: Although in the case of `int` to `Long` the answer is true, it isn't 100% correct, as autoboxing will happily convert from a compile-time constant `int` to `Short` for example.

Comment: My question concerns the pre-autoboxing phase, that is the casting. Still have not truly understood why the compiler rejects this cast operation: (Long)5

Comment: @biziclop  I would not specify this point as it is a corner case but for short literals you are right.

Comment: You cannot cast a primitive to a reference as you would. `5` is a primitive and casting it to `Long` should **first** respect autoboxing rules (here the boxing part : primitive to Object). In this specific case, `5` (an `int`) cannot be boxed to a `Long`. That's all.

Comment: @davidxxx Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The `long` is a primitive data type, but `Long` is a (wrapper) class.

The following should work.

```
System.out.println(add.apply(Long.valueOf(8), Long.valueOf(5)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ain't asking for the solution to my problem. I would rather like to know why the casting operation (Long)5 for instance fails.